# Extract higher and lower price list products

Tags: price, array

I need to extract the higher and lower price in category page.

My script:

```
<?php if($_product->isConfigurable()) { 

//get associative (child) products
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
                    $childPriceLowest = "";    
                    $childPriceHighest = "";  
                    $prezzo_pieno="";        
                    foreach($childProducts as $child){

                    $_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());


                    $prezzo_scontato =  $_child->getFinalPrice();
                    $prezzo_pieno_down=$_child->getPrice();

                    $price_array[] = array($prezzo_scontato);
                    $prezzo_pieno[]= array($prezzo_pieno_down); 

                    }
        asort($price_array);
        asort($prezzo_pieno);
        echo $price_array[0];
        echo $prezzo_pieno[0];

 }
```

does not work.

Print:

`arrayarray`

why? where is my error?

Answer (score 3):

```
$price_array[] = array($prezzo_scontato);
$prezzo_pieno[]= array($prezzo_pieno_down);
```

should be

```
$price_array[] = $prezzo_scontato;
$prezzo_pieno[]= $prezzo_pieno_down;
```